# T-SQL Group By summarize fields using logical functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I aggregate and arrive to these results?

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Column1
```

[image]

Comment: What is the data type of `column2` and `column3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the columns actually contain the literal string values `'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'`, we could use:

```
SELECT
    Column1,
    MAX(Column2) AS Column2,
    MAX(Column3) AS Column3
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    Column1;
```